# GIT list all commits by repro

Tags: git, github, git-log

Is there a command to list all commits for each repro in my "team"? was hoping there was a RSS feed that could be consumed but that doesn't look like the case. Worst case I can setup a service user and run git log on each and every repro but that also seems unnecessary

Comment: Would `git log`?

Comment: Do you mean for a repo, not a "repro"?

Answer (score -1):

There is no command like this for Git as Git doesn't keep track of repositories globally.

If you really want the feature, Fossil does exactly what you are asking for by recording the location of all repositories for a user. This allows you to run a command on all repositories using the "all" command.

So running `fossil all info` will give you exactly what you are asking for.

Here is a link to the documentation for the Fossil "all" command: http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/help?cmd=all

Comment: The question was about git and a lot of repositories. Do you think the author is going to learn a new VCS and convert all repos?

Comment: @phd That is why I explain that a feature like this does not exist in Git and pointed out where it could be found if the author really wanted it.